# Manipulating ASCII (.asc) files in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, ascii

I have an .asc file and I want to import in [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/).

The standard way to open it is from "add Raster layer" ("import Raster Layer") but is there another way?

I need to convert the .asc file to .tif or to another raster format with QGIS.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In QGIS, then the `Add Raster Layer` (menu or toolbar) is your best bet: `Layer: Add Raster Layer ...`. You could also use the Python console (see [the pyqgis cookbook](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/canvas.html)).

You may choose to load the layer, but you may also convert the file **without** adding it to your map canvas. Select the `Raster: Conversion: Translate (convert format)` menu option. The 'input layer' is your ASCII file, and the 'output file' will be a new file (choose the output format - TIFF or any of the 30 or so GDAL output types you will find there).

You may also choose to change the projection at this stage, choosing a new SRS.
[image: Raster translate screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way, apart from `Layer|Add Raster Layer...` is to just drag and drop it to the layers window. If you also want to translate it, then `Raster|Translate (Convert format)` is the tool for the job. All that does is wrap the command line tool `gdal_translate`, part of the excellent [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org) tools and library).