# Importing large .asc files into QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, data, large-datasets, esri-ascii-raster

I've been given two .asc files containing a 1m raster data from a LiDAR survey. I only have access to QGIS.2.14.1 (which I'am using for the 1st time only having previous experience with ArcGIS) and I am struggling to import the files due to their size given that they are 2.2 and 6GB respectively. Is there a function to reduce the size/mosaic the file to enable import in QGIS or any other program?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Robert! Perhaps this post might help: [Manipulate .asc files in qgis](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17607/manipulate-asc-files-in-qgis)

Comment: also see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1104/should-gdal-be-set-to-produce-geotiff-files-with-compression-which-algorithm-sh to convert them to much smaller (and faster) geotiffs

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

- 1st: convert to tif
- 2nd: create pyramids
- 3rd: see gdal tools (gdaladdo and gdal_convert) for more options