# ASCII-data source is not supported

Tags: qgis, error, ascii, esri-ascii-raster, data-source

I am using QGIS 2.18.15. I got some trouble to add an asc-file as a raster layer into QGIS. I tried to add the raster layer the normal way via the tool bar bottom. It did not work. (“The file source is not supported”)

Then I tried to convert the data via Raster: Conversion: Translate (convert format) menu option as it is suggested at StackExchange ([Manipulate .asc files in qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17607/manipulate-asc-files-in-qgis?newreg=581db7e000544e33b82b5755acbd6864)). It did no work ether. Here is the same problem “not recognized as a supported file format.”

[image]

The data I would like to add is from the following link. ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/grids_germany/multi_annual/solar/

It does not matter which data package I downloaded neither of them worked out.

Comment: They do work by using drag&drop from the browser. As alternative you can rename them to .xyz

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unzip files and then open them in your preferred text editor. Remove all header lines before `NCOLS`.

[image]

Then you can plot them on EPSG:31467 projection.

[image]

Comment: Make absolutely sure that you have word-wrap off, otherwise you will corrupt the raster.